# Open Calendar, Call Log and Google Mail

Tags: android

I have to open Android phones default Calendar , Call log, and Google Mails(list of mails)
what should be the intent for these  3 things?

If there is a 2 line code of opening an intent like we open gallery it is also fine, can anyone tell me ?
Or if there is another way to fetch this and show, it is fine too.

Please help me with these 3 things, anyhow i have to do this, either default of phone or creating my own activity

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

> I have to open Android phones default Calendar , Call log, and Google Mails(list of mails) what should be the intent for these 3 things?

For the call log, you can try an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the `Uri` supplied by `android.provider.CallLog.CONTENT_URI`, though I do not know if that works.

There are no documented and supported `Intents` for launching a "default Calendar" (whatever that is) or "Google Mails" (whatever that is).

Comment: default calendar means the calendar shows from menu when you purchase phone and same as gmail